# How to use SQLite3 C interface to load CSV file into a main memory database?

Tags: c, csv, sqlite

I know that there is a command line ".import" which can do this.
But if I want to do the same thing in C programs, what should I do?
And we are using the SQLite main memory database.
It means we have to do all things in one program. Otherwise, the database is cancelled after the connection is closed.
Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [how the command-line shell implements this](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/finfo?name=src/shell.c).

Comment: Thanks. But it seems that C cannot import csv into SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

The SQLite 3 C - API can be used to import csv into an Sqlite3 database.

- Your C code needs to open the CSV file, read in each line of the CSV
  file, making sure to store the column values (in the current row) in an
  appropriate container (i.e. column boundaries determined by comma separator).
- These column values can be bound to parameters in a prepared
  statement and then committed to the database.  Here is a useful link:
  http://blog.quibb.org/2010/08/fast-bulk-inserts-into-sqlite/

Comment: Tokenizing CVS input is non-trivial. Simple cases are simple, but I don't think there's even a universally recognized standard for, for example, how to represent fields that contain commas. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: There is a standard: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180